# Issue during rendering using C# in Compound Templating

Tags: tridion, tridion2009

A sudden issue appeared on one of the environments when publishing/rendering a certain piece of code in Compound Templating. It is an DTAP environment, and the issue is only happening on the Production environment (as always ;-), where there are two CMS machine and two publishers. All showing the same behavior.

The code which causes the problem is:

```
StructureGroup SG = (StructureGroup)engine.GetObject("/webdav/pub/root/etc/etc...");
```

The error in the Template builder is:

```
System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 10.77.66.136:80 
   bij System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress) 
   bij System.Net.Sockets.Socket.InternalConnect(EndPoint remoteEP) 
   bij System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Int32 timeout, Exception& exception) 
   --- Einde van intern uitzonderingsstackpad --- 
   bij System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(TransportContext& context) 
   bij System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream() 
   bij System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters) 
   bij Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.CompoundTemplates.DomainModel.Proxy.CompoundTemplateWebService.GetDebuggingState(String debuggerSessionId, String lastLogMessageId) 
   bij Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.CompoundTemplates.DomainModel.DebugObject.Start(Template template, Object debugItem, LoggingOptions loggingOptions)
```

What is odd that we are not really trying to get to an external server. At least, that's what it looks like. Maybe I am missing something in how Tridion works. I am fairly certain it is a security issue, but I don't know where to look.

Comment: It looks like you got an IP address in your stack trace.  Ping it, and find out what server in your architecture that is.

Comment: Can you specify your version of SDL Tridion?

Comment: I suspect your error is in Template builder? TOM.NET will NOT open a remote connection anywhere, and your error is in network communication... Can you try previewing or publishing in the CMS?

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys! It made me figure out there were two unrelated issues. One was about the location where I tried to run the Template Builder from, the other one had to do with some obscure content-created referencing loop in the Template Builder. Which I, of course, should never have allowed to happen in the first place!

Comment: Hi Hendrik, if you answer your own question you can accept that and may gain some up votes!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out the problem of the error with the help of Nickoli and Nuno's advice.

This error is shown when the Template Builder is trying to run from a location in a network, which doesn't have access to the code. I thought it was related to the **engine.GetObject** method, because the error would only appear when that method was run.

There was an error in the code in the end as well, but that had to do with a bad recursive method.